# Handle multiple get requests when mapping in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, promise, get

I have a component in which I `map()` through an array to render the child components.

This is a part of my code:

```js
// example pokemons
const pokemons = [
  {
    id: 1  
    name: "bulbasaur"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "ivysaur"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "venusaur"
  }
];

// map through pokemons
const mappedPokemons = pokemons.map((p, i) => {
  return <Pokemon key={i} pokemon={p} />;
});

// render
return (
  <div className="ml-3">
    <h1 className="text-center mb-5">Pokémons:</h1>
    <div className="row">{mappedPokemons}</div>
  </div>
);
```

In the child component, a get request is done using axios to get data from a public API ([pokeapi](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1)).

```js
const [pm, setPm] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + pokemon.id)
    .then((response) => {
      setPm(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, [pokemon.id]);
```

What I would like to achieve is to wait until all the data is received before rendering the components, I have heard about `Promise.all()` but am not sure on where to implement it if this would be the right approach.

I made this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-hill-g6928?file=/src/App.js) so you could try some things out.

Comment: What you're asking is pretty broad, but in general it sounds like you want to perform the AJAX requests in the parent component and then not display the child components until all requests are complete.  You can track the state to indicate that "data is loading" and update that state in the callback to `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the state gets put into the parent component, you can easily wait for all to resolve. Put the `pokemons` into state, then:

```
// parent
useEffect(() => {
  Promise.all(
    pokemons.map(p => axios
      .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + p.id)
      .then(res => res.data)
    )
  )
  .then((allData) => {
    const combined = pokemons.map((p, i) => ({ ...p, data: allData[i] }));
    setPokemons(combined);
  })
  .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this
}, []);
```

Then, only render the child components once `pokemons[0].data` exists, and use the data in the `pokemon` prop as needed.

Comment: Doing the fetch in the parent component makes sense now, thank you for helping. I think I just wanted to do the fetch in the child component because I don't always map through all the pokemons but just display a single one on the page sometimes but after thinking, I could and probably should also do this in the parent component.